# combining multiple csv data frames in r

Tags: r, dataframe, import, merge, rbind

I'm trying to combine a long list of data frames to one. 
every data frame is in a csv file. I tried:

`setwd("path")
file_names <- dir("path") 
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))`

but I got a data frame with one column. every row is one long list of all its data.

Comment: How do your csv files look like?

Comment: probably an issue of separator

Comment: And typically, when you have an error in a complex line, make it a 2 lines instruction and see which line is problematic. You'd have seen the problem here is not with the `lapply`

Comment: Sounds like the separator is not what you think it is. Perhaps a tab or a semicolon.